# executing external command (and reading its output) from a subrotine

Tags: perl

I am currently modifying a Perl script that executes several shell commands, and, for some of them, capture the output for further processing. I want to factor out the code that executes the external commands in subroutines. I wrote the following subroutines:

```
sub execute_command {
  my $cmd = shift;

  Log("executing command $cmd ...");
  system($cmd);
  my $app = ( $? == -1 ) ? $? : $? >> 8;
  if ($app != 0) {
    Log("error executing command $cmd");
    return $FAILURE;
  }
  Log("done");
  return $SUCCESS;
}

sub execute_command_and_get_output {
  my $cmd = shift;

  Log("executing command $cmd ...");
  unless (open( CMD, "$cmd|" )) {
    Log("error executing command $cmd");
    return undef;
  }
  my @cmd = <CMD>;
  close(CMD);
  Log("done");
  return @cmd;    
}
```

Questions:

1. `execute_command` should execute the passed command and return `$SUCCESS` if everything is OK, or `$FAILURE` in case of errors. Am I testing `$?` in the right way?
2. `execute_command_and_get_output` should execute the passed command and return the output as an array (containing the output lines); if the execution of the command fails, it should return `undef`. Is it correct to use `unless (open( CMD, "$cmd|" )) { ... }` to test for error conditions in the command execution?

Besides answers to my two questions, any suggestion for improvement is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) If you don't care what error has happened, it is enough to check return value of `system`:

```
if(system($cmd) == 0) { return $SUCCESS } else { return $FAILURE }
```

2) Instead of `return undef`, it is usually better to just `return`.  It works better when called in list context (it is still false). If the return is large, you might want to return reference to avoid copying.

Answer (score 1):

- `execute_command_and_get_output` can return two arguments:

  1. `$SUCCESS` or `$FAILURE`
  2. A reference to an array that either has the results or is empty
- `execute_command` can also return two arguments:

  1. `$SUCCESS` or `$FAILURE`
  2. An error message. For example:

     ```
     system ($cmd) == 0 or return ($FAILURE,"error executing command $cmd: $!");
     return ($SUCCESS, "done");
     ```
- BTW, you can avoid going through the `CMD` part using backticks (also, using the same name in more than one context is confusing).

  ```
      my @lines = `$cmd`;
      ($? == 0) or return ($FAILURE,"error executing command $cmd: $!");
      return ($SUCCESS, \@lines);
  ```

Comment: thank you for your answer: I appreciate the ideas, however I prefer to return multiple values from `execute_command_and_get_output`, and I don't line much the use of backticks.